# Pagination Ajax in Rails not working consistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, pagination

I have a rails app which I'm using will_paginate and ajax to paginate the the records.  I've read where the latest version of js/jquery depreciated the live() function so use on() or bind().

Now here's the problem.  I altered the code to use .on() and when I click a link it will reload the div with no page reload.  If I click on another page number link it will reload the page.  It only seems to work sporadically.

Below is the code I'm using.  Any ideas? This was from Railscast #240, btw.

```
  $("#display th a, #display .pagination a").on("click", function() {
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching, someone else posted up an answer that worked on Railscast.com.

Here's the code for those who need it.

```
$(document).on("click","#display th a, #display .pagination a", function() {
$.getScript(this.href);
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $("#display th a, #display .pagination a").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.href,
      dataType: 'script'
    });
    return false;
  });
  });
```